# DropdownButton inside a container with list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem. I want to create a dropdown where the user can select something from a list. But unfourtanly there is something missing and wrong. When I hover over `_DropdownButtonExampleState` 
it say `Missing concrete implementation of 'State.build'. (Documentation)  Try implementing the missing method, or make the class abstract.`
What is wrong and how can I solve the error ?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import '/FirstRoute.dart';




const List<String> list = <String>['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];

class DropdownButtonExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropdownButtonExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<DropdownButtonExample> createState() => _DropdownButtonExampleState();
}

class _DropdownButtonExampleState extends State<DropdownButtonExample> {
  String dropdownValue = list.first;
  

class IDRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const IDRoute ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  
  
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          systemOverlayStyle:
          const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.black),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
            onPressed: null,
          ),
          title: Text("Welcome my app",
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center)
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const Text("YourID",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 50.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                      color: Color(0XFF3F3D56),
                      height: 2.0)),
            const Text("Please enter your ID.",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  letterSpacing: 1.2,
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  height: 1.3),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
  DropdownButton<String>(
  value: dropdownValue,
  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
  elevation: 16,
  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
  underline: Container(
  height: 2,
  color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
  ),
  onChanged: (String? value) {
  // This is called when the user selects an item.
  setState(() {
  dropdownValue = value!;
  });
  },
  items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
  value: value,
  child: Text(value),
  );
  }).toList(),
  ),
              
              
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Open route'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const FirstRoute()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CAN NOT create a class within a class! I removed it for you. Copy this and you will not get the Error anymore:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

const List<String> list = <String>['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];

class DropdownButtonExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropdownButtonExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<DropdownButtonExample> createState() => _DropdownButtonExampleState();
}

class _DropdownButtonExampleState extends State<DropdownButtonExample> {
  String dropdownValue = list.first;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          systemOverlayStyle: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.black),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
            onPressed: null,
          ),
          title: Text("Welcome my app", style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white), textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const Text("YourID", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, color: Color(0XFF3F3D56), height: 2.0)),
              const Text(
                "Please enter your ID.",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, letterSpacing: 1.2, fontSize: 16.0, height: 1.3),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              DropdownButton<String>(
                value: dropdownValue,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                elevation: 16,
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                underline: Container(
                  height: 2,
                  color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                ),
                onChanged: (String? value) {
                  // This is called when the user selects an item.
                  setState(() {
                    dropdownValue = value!;
                  });
                },
                items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Open route'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const FirstRoute()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```